# Snake case to lower camel case with regex and sed

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to find a proper regex that matches the pattern "some_text".local for `sed`

`("\w*?"\.local)` does the job of finding `"...".local` match,
`_(.)/\U\1` will find all underscores and replace it with upper case letter next to it.
But i don't know how to combine them together so the result would look like this:

```
self.title = "statistics_title".local
self.title = "title".local
```

->

```
self.title = L10n.statisticsTitle
self.title = L10n.title
```

I use `find . -name "*.swift" -exec gsed -r -i 's/_(.)/\U\1/gi' {} +` cmd to search and replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `sed` loop for that:

```
sed -r '
    :loop
    s/_([^"]+"\.local)/\u\1/
    t loop

    s/"([^"]+)"\.local/L10n.\1/g
' file.swift
```

Explanation:

- The first `s` only changes one `_seq` to `Seq` at a time. Thus, the command is done repeatedly until nothing is matching the pattern `_([^"]+"\.local)` (.local definition in snake case).  `t loop` means "Go to `loop` if the last `s` command was successful.
- The second `s` command just turns all `"fooBar".local` into `L10n.fooBar`

You can put everyting in one line by using the `;` separator:

```
 find . -name "*.swift" -exec gsed -r -i ':loop; s/_([^"]+"\.local)/\u\1/g; t loop; s/"([^"]+)"\.local/L10n.\1/g' {} +
```

Comment: You're welcome. Your problem was very well explained to us. That's very unusual for a first question. Thank you for that.